# Carousel not initializing due to ReferenceError: onSlideStart is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue carousel that isn't quite working correctly.

I have the example carousel code [from the examples](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/carousel).  I've included this script inside of the `<div>`:

```
  <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          slide: 0,
          sliding: null
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onSlideStart (slide) {
          this.sliding = true
        },
        onSlideEnd (slide) {
          this.sliding = false
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

But, I'm still getting this error:

```
vue.min.js:6 ReferenceError: onSlideStart is not defined
    at Rt.eval (eval at Tn (vue.min.js:6), <anonymous>:2:271)
    at Rt.t._render (vue.min.js:6)
    at Rt.r (vue.min.js:6)
    at Kr.get (vue.min.js:6)
    at new Kr (vue.min.js:6)
    at vue.min.js:6
    at Rt.$mount (vue.min.js:6)
    at Rt.$mount (vue.min.js:6)
    at Rt.t._init (vue.min.js:6)
    at new Rt (vue.min.js:6)
```

Comment: Are you using single file components (*.vue) or are you using the runtime method?

Comment: Currently straight into an .erb

Comment: Does it have to be its own component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a noob to vue, I just realized that I can do this at runtime with the following

```
  new Vue({el: '#carousel',
    data: {
      slide: 0,
      sliding: null
    },
    methods: {
      onSlideStart: function(slide) {
        this.sliding = true
      },
      onSlideEnd: function(slide) {
        this.sliding = false
      }
    }
  })
```